# django: Recursive function called in views.py method not returning results

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am new to django and web development, I am trying to call a recursive function in views.py on clicking submit button on my form.

When I try to call the same function while it returns a simple list, it works fine, but it returns nothing if the core logic is enabled. I am really not sure what's the problem, can anyone tell what's wrong and how to fix it?

Following is the implementation of views.py and recursive function:

```
def process_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Request is POST")
        form = UIForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid")
            # Create an instance of the model and assign the form data to its fields
            form_data = FormData()
            form_data.from_timestamp = form.cleaned_data['from_timestamp']
            form_data.to_timestamp = form.cleaned_data['to_timestamp']
            form_data.free_text = form.cleaned_data['free_text']
            form_data.uploaded_file = form.cleaned_data['file']

            # Save the form data to the database
            form_data.save()
            file = request.FILES['file']

            todayDate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            dest_dir = temp_directory + os.sep + todayDate
            dest_path = dest_dir + os.sep + file.name
            os.makedirs(dest_dir, exist_ok=True)
            print("Dest path:", dest_path)
            # Handle the uploaded file
            if file:
                # Save the file to the server's temporary directory
                with open(f'{dest_path}', 'wb') as destination:
                    for chunk in file.chunks():
                        destination.write(chunk)

            # Check the given regular expression against the extracted files
            pattern = form_data.free_text
            extracted_dir = extract_files_and_return_list_of_paths(dest_path)
            matching_files = search_files_for_pattern(extracted_dir, pattern)

            print("matching_files:", matching_files)
            for i in range(len(matching_files)):
                print("matching_files[", i, "]:", matching_files[i])

            # Store the matching_files list in the session
            request.session['matching_files'] = matching_files

            # Create the JSON response data
            response_data = {
                'success': True,
                'pk': form_data.pk,
                'matching_files': matching_files
            }
            return JsonResponse(response_data)
        else:
            # Return JSON response with errors if the form is invalid
            errors = json.loads(form.errors.as_json())
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': errors})

    else:
        form = UIForm()

    return render(request, 'ui.html', {'form': form})
```

Recursive function is:

```
def search_files_for_pattern(directory, pattern):
    matching_files = list()
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):  # Filter for text files
            with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
                file_contents = file.read()
                if re.search(pattern, file_contents):
                    #print("Found pattern in file:", file_path)
                    matching_files.append(file_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
            search_files_for_pattern(file_path, pattern)  # Recursively search subdirectories
    for i in range(len(matching_files)):
        print(matching_files[i])
    return matching_files
```

Above process_form is getting invoked from below script in ui.html:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '{% url "process_form" %}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: jsonData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    xhr:function(){
                        const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', e=>{
                            if(e.lengthComputable){
                                const percentProgress = (e.loaded/e.total)*100;
                                console.log(percentProgress);
                                progress_bar.innerHTML = `<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success"
                        role="progressbar" style="width: ${percentProgress}%" aria-valuenow="${percentProgress}" aria-valuemin="0"
                        aria-valuemax="100"></div>`
                            }
                        });
                        return xhr
                    },
                    success: function(jsonData) {
                        // Extract the pk value from the server's response
                        var pk = jsonData.pk;
                        const matchingFiles = jsonData.matching_files;
                        // Check if pk is available before redirecting
                        console.log("pk value (function):", jsonData.pk);
                        if (pk) {
                            // Construct the URL with the pk and redirect to the result_page
                            var resultPageUrl = '{% url "result_page" %}' + pk + '/';  // Update the URL according to your URL patterns
                            // Pass the matching_files list as a parameter in the URL
                            resultPageUrl += '?matching_files=' + JSON.stringify(matchingFiles);
                            window.location.href = resultPageUrl;
                        } else {
                            alert('Error occurred during upload. Please try again.');
                            $('#upload_btn').prop('disabled', false);
                            $('.progress').hide();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Error occurred during upload. Please try again.');
                        $('#upload_btn').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Is there a carriage return or new line at the end of form_data.free_text ?

Comment: No, there is no new line or carriage return, but how it might impact? log added inside search_files_for_pattern(extracted_dir, pattern) is getting printed and I could see the list is getting appended but in I get empty in process_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found where the problem is, Problem is in the Recursive function search_files_for_pattern should be modified as:

```
def search_files_for_pattern(directory, pattern):
    matching_files = list()
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):  # Filter for text files
            with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
                file_contents = file.read()
                if re.search(pattern, file_contents):
                    #print("Found pattern in file:", file_path)
                    matching_files.append(file_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
            return search_files_for_pattern(file_path, pattern)  # Recursively search subdirectories
    for i in range(len(matching_files)):
        print(matching_files[i])
    return matching_files
```

Need to return the recursive function in the else block to avoid internal loop.